# Two versions of libboost

Tags: compiling, boost

I'm using ndnSIM simulator which needs a libboost to be installed, when I try to run any code, I got the following error:

---

```
usr/local/lib/libns3-dev-emu-optimized.so: undefined reference to ns3::Queue::Dequeue()'
/usr/local/lib/libns3-dev-emu-optimized.so: undefined reference to ns3::CallbackBase::Demangle(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libns3-dev-emu-optimized.so: undefined reference to ns3::Queue::GetTypeId()'
/usr/local/lib/libns3-dev-emu-optimized.so: undefined reference to ns3::LogComponent::LogComponent(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, ns3::LogLevel)'
/usr/local/lib/libns3-dev-emu-optimized.so: undefined reference to ns3::Queue::Enqueue(ns3::Ptr<ns3::Packet>)'
/usr/local/lib/libns3-dev-emu-optimized.so: undefined reference to ns3::TypeId::AddAttribute(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, ns3::AttributeValue const&, ns3::Ptr<ns3::AttributeAccessor const>, ns3::Ptr<ns3::AttributeChecker const>)'
/usr/local/lib/libns3-dev-emu-optimized.so: undefined reference to ns3::PcapHelper::CreateFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::_Ios_Openmode, unsigned int, unsigned int, int)'
/usr/local/lib/libns3-dev-emu-optimized.so: undefined reference to typeinfo for ns3::Queue'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

I read that this might be a result of having two boost libraries. So I run the locate command and got the following output

---

```
locate libboost_system

/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libboost_system.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0
/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.a
/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so
/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so.1.62.0
```

---

Is this the reason why I got the error? How can I upgrade or remove the oldest version without affecting my simulator?

Comment: there is a conflict between header files it found while building and library files while linking. Try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` before building your project

Comment: This did not work as the simulator need to be configured with boost 1.62.0 so I configure it as follow ( as written in the simulator manual )  `./waf configure --boost-includes=/usr/local/include --boost-libs=/usr/local/lib`  the instructions are available in (https://ndnsim.net/2.4/faq.html#installing-boost-libraries)